# Create JAR with one file in Maven

Tags: maven, jar

I have pretty standard Maven build following default lifecycle phases. However, at the beginning I need to generate to `target` directory JAR file with just one particular resource and then continue the build. How can I do it using standard plugins?

At http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/plugin-info.html I see only possiblity to generate JAR for entire project.

Comment: Make a separate module which contains the special folder and that's it...No special configurations etc...

Comment: What kind of resources? Can you show use your pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise it's just one XML file that I want to have as separate JAR. Tunaki already provided working answer, thanks

Comment: What i don't understand is where is this XML file coming from? Does it exist in the same module? And why do you need a JAR which contains only a single file? For what purpose ? This setup sounds wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise This is XML with a schema used by my app that I need to distribute as JAR. Yes, it exists in the same module. What's wrong with that? And yes, at some point I will create a separate module for that, but now I needed it just for playing around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `maven-jar-plugin` for this task by specifying a [`classesDirectory`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classesDirectory):

> Directory containing the classes and resource files that should be packaged into the JAR.

By default, this points to `${project.build.outputDirectory}` in order to make a JAR of the classes and resources of your entire project.

Within this folder, you can then select what specific resource you want to include with the [`includes`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#includes) parameter. An example of configuration would be the following:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>init-jar</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <classesDirectory>${basedir}/path/to/folder</classesDirectory>
                <includes>
                    <include>resource.txt</include>
                </includes>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <finalName>resource</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will make a JAR out of the file `${basedir}/path/to/folder/resource.txt` inside the build folder. This JAR will be named `resource.jar`, as per the configured `finalName`. The execution is bound to the `initialize` phase since you want to create this JAR at the beginning of the build.